# non-binary/gender independence in formal greetings

Tags: idiomaticity, gender-neutrality

One formal greeting is: "sehr geehrte Damen und Herren", however this greeting implicitly excludes those who don't identify as either male or female. My question is if there is a standard general way to include non-binary or others who don't quite fit into either male or female in German.

While "Hello/Welcome/Dear everyone" is a potential address in English, it feels like a lot less formal then "Dear/Welcome/- ladies and gentlemen", and I would imagine the German translation would similarly lack this formality. A possible English translation of what I'm searching for is "Ladies, gentlemen, and members of unspecified genders" (not quite a general phrase I'd use, but would be tweaked depending on situation ect).

Comment: Since people, who don't identify as male or female, are very, very, very rare, it is a far stretched assumption, that an everyday phrase implicitly excludes somebody. Many people have never even heard of people, who don't identify as some sex.

Comment: For example, LGBT people all identify with a gender. And some others. That’s the majority of the minority.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to what was already said:

Alternatively, depending on the occasion, you could avoid to address the crowd directly at all.

In many circumstances, something like this will work just as well:

> Einen guten Abend wünsche ich Ihnen allen. Ich freue mich, dass Sie sich die Zeit genommen haben. ...  Ich möchte heute über ... sprechen ...

No one will notice the wokeness though. Something like "Sehr geehrte Tagungsteilnehmende!" is obviously much more explicit if signaling virtue is part of the goal. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

We had a similiar question about email headings. In a in person meeting, you could use phrases like

> Liebe(s)/Sehr geehrte(s)...
> ...Teilnehmende
> ...Publikum

Comment: No idea why this was downvoted.

Answer (score 3):

To fulfil what that useless genderism triggers, the logical answer is you have to add a third component to your greeting to adapt it to the "modern" development:

> Sehr geehrte Damen, Herren und Diverse

This will accept *Diverse* as fully equal to *Damen* and *Herren*.

Though you will get the problem of who is first in the order and could complain to be mentioned not first... (facepalm)

I recommend a traditional greeting to you since a greeting should not provoke with a very controversial society discussion.

Answer (score 1):

The formulation "Dear Sir or Madam!" is sufficient when addressing people of both male and female gender. When more than two genders are to be addressed, there are various formulation options. There are gender-neutral ways of writing that include all people. The gender asterisk or gender gap can be used or the specific target group can be addressed.

- Guten Tag!
- Sehr geehrtes Team der Muster GmbH!
- Sehr geehrter Kundenservice der TeleGesell!
- Sehr geehrte Führungskräfte!
- Sehr geehrte Beschäftigte!
- Sehr geehrtes Publikum!
- Sehr geehrte Tagungsteilnehmende!
- Sehr geehrte Anwesende!
- Sehr geehrtes Kollegium!
- Sehr Geehrte!
- Sehr geehrte Zuständige!
- Sehr geehrte Abteilung B!
- Liebes Team!
- Liebes Team der Abteilung B!
- Liebe Menschen!
- …

By the way: In the case of a specific person whose gender is not known, the greeting "Good day first name last name" (Good day Julia Müller!) is now common practice.

(Answer was copied/translated from https://geschicktgendern.de/tipps-und-tricks/faq/, third FAQ: "Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren!". You might also be interested in https://www.gendern.de/ and https://www.genderleicht.de/.)

Comment: "Dear Sir or Madam!" ist aber nicht Deutsch.

Comment: 'the greeting "Good day first name last name" (Good day Julia Müller!) is now common practice' - I wouldn't quite go that far. IMHO, e-mails and letters written that way primarily evoke the idea that the sender is using a cheap/unsophisticated mail-merge software that just pastes the full name verbatim rather than caring for things like given name, surname, form of address, etc.; not that the sender was trying to be particularly considerate concerning gender identities. That notwithstanding, it is probably a good idea to help establish this pattern as it makes many things easier.

Comment: @userunknown: Mit dem ganzen Denglish ist die Unterscheidung öfters schwierig, aber hier gebe ich Dir/Ihnen recht.